# Ethernet port configuration utility?

Tags: windows, utility

I am developing hardware that communicates via Ethernet, and as part of the testing often have to switch a single port between two or more different configurations (such as DHCP vs. static IP- with different IPs).

Is there some utility that would allow different port configurations to be stored and easily accessed with a click or two. Alternately, what would be a good scripting approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell could script it - example:

```
$wmi = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -filter "ipenabled = 'true'"
$wmi.EnableStatic("10.0.0.15", "255.255.255.0")
$wmi.SetGateways("10.0.0.1", 1)
$wmi.SetDNSServerSearchOrder("10.0.0.100")
```

More info here:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/02/28/use-powershell-to-configure-static-ip-and-dns-settings/

Comment: Looks perfect for the application.